# Glossy effect when clicking on UINavigationBar button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

When I'm clicking on a `UIButton` that located on the top of `UINavigationBar` I have this glossy effect:

[image: glossy]

How can I add this effect to another button that located on a `UINavigatonBar` but not as a left or right  button item? like this:

```
UIButton * emptyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[emptyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(119, 5, 82, 35)];
[emptyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(centerNavigationBarTitleClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[emptyButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:emptyButton];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to set the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property to `YES` to get the glow effect, i.e.

```
emptyButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```